# Log design approach

Tags: c#, oop, logging

Logging was always a nightmare for me! Now I have to implement it again for a proxy system.
In this proxy application, some systems ask proxy system to call some other services.
What I have to log is

- Request Time
- Requester IP
- Request Parameters as XML
- Requested Service Name
- Requested Service Method
- Response Time
- Response data as XML
- Response Message (If any exception occurs it will logged as Message)

I considered to append two lines to my methods:

```
// Log Request
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Logger.Log(RequestParameters.ToXML(),Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, DateTime.Now));

// Invoke requested service and get response

// Log Response
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Logger.Log(Response.ToXML(), DateTime.Now));
```

I also want to log nested transactions.

Assume a transaction contains a request and a response. A transaction may contains many other internal transactions. When I receive a request, I should register a transaction, and insert a request for it, later, when response received, I should update the transaction response. Please note that I'm trying to store request and response relationship for better tracking.

How can I safely add this logging procedure to methods? I want to restrict developers to implement this logging systems in all methods, some thing like interface or inheritance for method body is required. Can I do this by attributes? Then how?

Comment: Why not use IIS logging capabilities ? It can log all details about requests and with a good tool you can extract info you need in case it is actually needed, at usually that is rare.

Comment: ... or use an existing logging framework? log4net or nlog spring to mind.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are developing exactly, but I have used custom Attribute, IServiceBehaviour, and IParameterInspector to implemnt custom loggin in a WCF service. I have also used system.diagnostics in the web.config to log critical errors to a tracelistener file.

Comment: [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) uses logging as its basic example. I hear [post#](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects) is good, but I'm a java (aspectj) man so take that with a grain of salt :)

Comment: @PetarRepac: Then, is there any chance to provide a readable console for Application Admin, so that he track the system communication easily? Or IIS log is a complex text log with sophisticated reporting capabilities?

Comment: @AnthonyQueen: Please note that transactions are nested. Many service invocations happen in Business Logic via a general Proxy Helper. So, I can not rely on exposed WCF services only.

Comment: @spender: I checked NLog, that's really fantastic. But what I missed is the relation between logged items. I mean I want to store the relation between requests and responses. Can I do that with NLog?

Comment: I don't think it can be done as a feature of nlog. You could always tag the log entries with some sort of identifier (a counter or a guid) to relate the two together, no?

Comment: @spender: well, maybe I can do it with a GUID. So I can find a response related request. But, how about nested requests? Assume request1 from system1 to proxy leads request2 from proxy to system2 and so on. I'm not sure how can I implement it with NLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why re-invent the wheel, you can use nlog or microsoft patterns and practices logging library; someone already answered this in detail here [What are the guidelines for designing an application-wide logging system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987193/what-are-the-guidelines-for-designing-an-application-wide-logging-system?rq=1)

I use logstash a lot, but your seems to be a c# intensive work.